# jquery validate don't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

My problem is that when I click the submit button the form is submitted but is not validated before.

usually when you click the submit button and the form is validated and sent only if everything is ok

Check out my code

```
<form action="http://localhost/Localizze/auth/register.html" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="singup-form" novalidate="novalidate">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="input-block-level" id="name" placeholder="Digite seu nome">                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="" class="input-block-level" id="email" placeholder="Digite seu email">                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="input-block-level" id="password" placeholder="Digite uma senha">                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" name="confirmation_password" value="" class="input-block-level" id="confirmation_password" placeholder="Digite sua senha">                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">

               (<input type="text" name="ddd" value="" maxlength="2" class="input-ddd" id="ddd" placeholder="DDD">) <input type="text" name="celular" value="" maxlength="9" class="input-celular" id="celular" placeholder="Celular">                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-prepend" style="width: 95%;margin-bottom: 20px;">
                        <span class="add-on">@</span><input type="text" name="twitter" value="" class="input-block-level" id="twitter" placeholder="Usuário do Twitter">                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        Entendo que o Localizze não é afiliado aos Correios e não pode resolver problemas sobre minha encomenda. <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" id="agree" style="margin-top:-8px;">                        </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Enviar</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-large">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#singup-form').validate(
        {
            rules: {
                name: {
                    minlength: 3,
                    required: true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                password: {
                    required: true
                },
                confirmation_password: {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: '#password'
                },
                ddd: {
                    ignore: ''
                },
                celular: {
                    number: true,
                    minlength: 8
                },
                twitter: {
                    minlength: 3
                },
                agree: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            highlight: function(label) {
                $(label).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
            },
            success: function(label) {
                label
                        .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');

            }
        });
}); // end document.ready
```

**Why the form is not verified and validated before submit?**

Comment: novalidate="novalidate" ???? Also press F12 and look in the console

Comment: @mplungjan novalidate is an attribute for HTML5.  It's added so that form can be validated separately with jQuery.

Comment: It has nothing related novalidate = "novalidate"

Comment: @GrailsGuy Ah, thanks... Renato - can you make a jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no built in function ignore - delete that and should be ok

```
ddd: {
 // ignore: ''
},
```

Comment: I've been reading around, you could use the ignore fields that do not wish to validation ... you're right, it worked correctly.

thank you all